# Java Lambda expression Parameter data type

Tags: java, string, list, lambda, foreach

```
public class Example{
  public static void main(String[] args){
  List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
   list.add("Rick");
   list.add("Negan");
    list.add("carl");

    list.forEach(
      (names)->System.out.println(names)
    );
  }
}
```

In this example, how is the type of `names` inferred.
What happens, if we add items with a different data type.
For example:

```
list.add(new Person());
list.add(new Integer(3);
```

Comment: Have you tried any of the examples? Those wont work for `List<String>`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more of generic question if I understand it correctly.
When you declare `List<String> namesList`  meaning you can add only string and its sub types in `namesList`. If try to add something else compile will complain as it knows from the declaration of `namesList` that it can have on String types values.

Answer (score 0):

Such situation is possible only if you create list of generic object type:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Object> list= new ArrayList<>();

        list.add("Rick");
        list.add(new Person());
        list.add(new Integer(3);

        list.forEach(name->System.out.println(name));
    }
}
```

[System.out.println(Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object-) method will be called, so according to doc:

> Prints an Object and then terminate the line. This method calls at first String.valueOf(x) to get the printed object's string value, then behaves as though it invokes print(String) and then println().

Generally Java never had true type inference like dynamic languages.

Answer (score 0):

> In this example, how is the type of `names` inferred

What is happening under the hood is that *javac* is inferring the type of the variable `names` from its *context* i.e. from the signature of `Consumer` as `forEach` in your specific example consumes a `Consumer<String>`.

So, you may ask how is *javac* doing this? without going into too much detail *javac* looks for information close to your lambda expression and uses this information to figure out what the correct type should be.

That said, *javac* cannot always infer the types in which case you'll need to provide type hints.

> What happens, if we add items with a different data type.

You'll get a compilation error. This is one of the benefits that generics have provided *stronger type checks at compile time*.

i.e. the `javac` applies strong type checking to generic code and issues errors if the code violates type safety. The benefit of this is that fixing compile-time errors is a lot easier than fixing runtime errors.